# use the live preview feature in the plugin

Tags: plugins

I want to preview a post or page in the plugin I am developing, does anyone know how this can be done?

In the example scenario, I am developing an animation in my plugin, for example, I want to have a live preview to see how it will look on the homepage, my goal is to build a structure similar to the customise feature of themes.